# Why are individual apps not listed in my battery usage statistics?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, battery-life

I'm using an Asus Transformer TF300 running Ice Cream Sandwich. When I check `Settings->Battery` the only things listed are Screen, Tablet Idle and Wifi. Why aren't apps that I use being shown in these statistics?

Answer (score 4):

The only apps shown there are the ones using significant (>=1%) battery. If the app is not particularly resource intensive, it won't show up there.